# how to use intent to pick a xml file and parse it dynamically

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, apk

I wanted to use intent to pick a xml file inside of my app and then parse it dynamically. I know the parsing and showing process but my main problem is with the inputstream . Please notice that picking xml should be done dynamically not in assets . can anyone help me plz?

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==PICKFIlE_RESULT_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            File file = null;



            String filepath = data.getData().getPath();
            file = new File(filepath);
            String v = file.getAbsolutePath();
            try
            {

                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(v);
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
                Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
                element.normalize();
                NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("user");

                for(int i=0;i<nList.getLength();i++)
                {
                    Node node = nList.item(i);
                    if(node.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    {
                        Element element2 = (Element)node;
                        textView.setText(textView.getText()+"\nName : "+getValue("name",element2)+"\n");
                        textView.setText(textView.getText()+"\nSurname : "+getValue("surname",element2)+"\n");
                        textView.setText(textView.getText()+"\nSalary : "+getValue("salary",element2)+"\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }



public void onClick(View v) {
final static private int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE =10;

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("file/*");

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFIlE_RESULT_CODE);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No file found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show how you are using `startActivityForResult()` with `PICKFIlE_RESULT_CODE` that triggers this `onActivityResult()`. Please note that a `Uri` is not a file, and `getPath()` frequently is useless as a result.

Comment: Tnx for your attention . I attached the code u wanted and please notice that pickfile_result_code has been defined globally in this activity but I pasted here so u can see easily .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `file/*` is not a valid MIME type. Use a valid MIME type, or `*/*` if you want to accept anything.

Second, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` returns a `Uri`. That `Uri` is not a file. Get rid of all your `File` logic. Use a `ContentResolver` (from `getContentResolver()`) and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.